# How to use Azure SDK to Create resource of Type "Web App bot" in c# .net core

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I tried to create resource of type "Web App" and it is work, But I need to Create a resource of type "Web App Bot"

```
        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(ClientId, SecretId, TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var azure = Azure
                        .Configure()
                        .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                        .Authenticate(credentials)
                        .WithSubscription(subscribtionId);

        var dd = azure.WebApps.Define("mrecourceName")
            .WithRegion(Region.AsiaEast)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup("mygroupName").
            WithNewFreeAppServicePlan().Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Azure does not provide a resource type of web app bot. When you create web app bot, you need to create Azure bot service and azure app service. And, now, we cannot use Azure .NET SDK to create bot service. For more details, please refer to

https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services